# show tab1 results on tab2 by clicking links (bootstrap + angularjs2)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Here is what i'm trying to achieve using bootstrap modal.

1. When user clicks on a button, a modal opens up with multiple tabs
2. The tab1 contains links, if the user clicks on links it should show its results (i.e., sub-links) on tab2
3. if user clicks on tab2 sub-links then the results should be showed on tab3....(which i will implement later)

Here is my code:

```js
ngular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Link', '$document', '$http', function($scope, Link, $document, $http) {
        $scope.list_links = function() {
            $scope.links = [];
            $scope.showLoading = true;
            $scope.showSlinkList = false;
            $scope.showLinkList = true;
            $scope.linkPromise = Link.query().$promise.then(function(resp) {
                $scope.links = resp;
                $scope.showLoading = false;
            });
            

        $scope.loadSlinks = function(linkId) {
            $scope.slinks = []
            $scope.showLinkList = false;
            $scope.showLoading = true;
            $scope.showSlinkList = true;
            $scope.linkId = linkId;
            $scope.slinkPromise = $http.get('/api/links/' + linkId + '/slinks').then(function(resp) {
                $scope.showLoading = false;
                $scope.slinks = resp.data;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Links">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Links" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="LinksLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Your Links</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div role="tabpanel">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#chooseAlink" aria-controls="browseTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Choose A Link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#chooseAsublink" aria-controls="browseTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >Choose A Sub-Link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panes --> 
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="chooseAlink">

                         <div ng-show="showLinkList" class="container text-center how-works" ng-class="{loading: showLoading}">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         <a ng-repeat="link in links" ng-click="loadSublinks(link.id)" class="col-xs-4">
         
          <div>{{link.name}}</div>
         </a>
         </div>
         
        </div>
        <div cg-busy="{promise:brandPromise}"></div>
        
       </div>




                        
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="#chooseAsublink">

       <div ng-show="showSubLinkList" class="container text-center how-works" ng-class="{loading: showLoading}">
        <div class="models row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         <a ng-repeat="slink in slinks" class="col-xs-2" ng-href="/links/{{linksId}}/slinks/{{item.id}}/items">
          <div>{{slink.name}}</div>
         </a>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>



       </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created above modal with tabs however not able move the tab1 results to tab2. Please help me how i can achieve this. Also not sure how to use Next & Back buttons to switch between tabs without loosing tab1 data.